# I want to lambdify a function written in sympy

Tags: sympy, lambdify

In sympy I write a function like this:

```
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x y')
def Func(x,y):
   return sin(x) + cos(y)
```

All works fine, but I find no way to lambdify this, e.g.

```
Func_lam = lambdify(x, y, Func)
z = Func_lam(1,2)
```

gives an error, it says this is deprecated.
I would greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The first arg to lambdify should be an iterable and the second, an expression. You passed 3 arguments and your third is not an expression, it is a function that will return an expression when you tell it what the args are. Compare what you have to this:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> def Func(x,y): return sin(x) + cos(y)
>>> x, y = symbols('x y')
>>> f = lambdify((x,y), Func(x,y))
>>> f(1,2)
0.4253241482607541
```

Comment: Thank you  VERY much!!! Really helped my understanding